# Is Status 204 Correct when invoking Native Soft Delete through the REST API

Tags: json, azure, postman

I'm trying to test out the preview feature Native Soft Delete for Azure Blob Storage. On the page, it specifies using the REST API to invoke it. In my initial test, i'm almost certain the success code was 400,  and it returned something to me, but now i'm trying to invoke it on a new data source, it's returning Status 204.

Is this correct? I'm using Postman to query the API as below:

```
{
    "name" : "nativesoft",
    "type" : "azureblob",
    "credentials" : { "connectionString" : "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=nativeblobstorage;AccountKey=sH0mT/fILQwwnTmJ8XWq5fFM/Z1wSv8XZnJ0gjryl5XDt7PygA/tm1I5B0/9dsAVZCJd5aI5yzoF+ASt62KJsg==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net" },
    "container" : { "name" : "native-delete-test", "query" : null },
    "dataDeletionDetectionPolicy" : {
        "@odata.type" :"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.NativeBlobSoftDeleteDeletionDetectionPolicy"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered via trial and error that 204 is an incorrect response to this as this piece of code creates a new data source in Cognitive Search.

If you give parameters of an already existing data source, then Status 204 will be returned, if you give new parameters, then it will return Status 201 created.

In the example of the code posted above, it also returned this in the body for my query:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://nativeblobtestsearch.search.windows.net/$metadata#datasources/$entity",
    "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DA85D739C61289\"",
    "name": "blob-datasource",
    "description": null,
    "type": "azureblob",
    "subtype": null,
    "credentials": {
        "connectionString": null
    },
    "container": {
        "name": "native-delete-test",
        "query": null
    },
    "dataChangeDetectionPolicy": null,
    "dataDeletionDetectionPolicy": {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.NativeBlobSoftDeleteDeletionDetectionPolicy"
    },
    "encryptionKey": null
}
```

Hopefully this is helpful for anyone else struggling with similar issues!